# AWS SAM Access to more than one bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sam

I have a simple SAM template, and the following snippet grants access to an S3 bucket:

```
      Policies:
        - S3CrudPolicy:
            BucketName: "bucket-a"
```

But I need to allow access to two buckets, `bucket-a` and `bucket-b`. How should I do it. The docs say the `BucketName` is a string. Does it accept an array or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Policies` is an **array**. Thus the following should theoretically work:

```
 Policies:
    - S3CrudPolicy:
        BucketName: "bucket-a"
    - S3CrudPolicy:
        BucketName: "bucket-b"
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thanks.